# Typescript Formatting in Netbeans

Tags: typescript, netbeans, format

I have started to use typescript in netbeans. I have installed typescript plugin [typescript-netbeans](https://github.com/Everlaw/nbts/releases). This recogonises the typescript code. But the normal code formatting option (Alt + Shift + F) doesn't seem to work for typescript. Indentations have to done manually as of now. 
Is there any solution for it ?

**Netbeans version - 10.0**

**Typescript plugin - 3.0.1**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this and it works fine for me using NetBeans 10. These are the steps I followed:

- Install version 3.0.1 of the **TypeScript Editor** plugin you linked to:

  [image: installPlugin]
- Download and install TypeScript using `npm install -g typescript`:

  [image: npmTypeScript]
- Create a simple NetBeans project (**File > New Project... > HTML5/JavaScript > HTML5/JS Application**).
- Create a TypeScript file (**File > New File... > Other > TypeScript File**) within the project.
- In the TypeScript file just created, right click and select **TypeScript Setup...** from the context menu.
- The **TypeScript Setup** dialog opens. Click **Browse...** and select the path of your **Lib directory**. In my case this was the directory **C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib** (containing **typescript.js**) that I had just created using **npm**:

  [image: libSetup]

Once the setup process is complete, create some content in the TypeScript file which is poorly formatted:

```
function                            greeter(person) {
return "Hello, "                     + person;
                            }
                          let user  =           "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML          = greeter(user);
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to reformat the code:

```
function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person;
}
let user = "Jane User";

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

If you are still having problems, post any relevant messages from the NetBeans error log (**View > IDE Log**).

Notes:

- You can configure the formatting to be performed automatically whenever you save the file: **Tools > Options > Editor > On Save > Language: TypeScript**:

  [image: onSave]
- Although there is no option to explicitly specify TypeScript formatting, you can specify that JavaScript formatting is to be used for your project by default, which should be appropriate most of the time. Select your project in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **Formatting** from the **Categories** list in the **Project Properties** window:

  [image: projectFormatting]